# Polling directory with multiple sub-directories

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

I am trying to build a simple utility that will copy the files from multiple directories from one sftp server to another server.

I tried use sftp outbound gateway to poll single high level directory with command "mget" , but it did not work. So I thought of writing two inbound adapters ( not a good solution, but still wanted this to be done badly !) .

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="pdbInbound"
         session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"        
         auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true"
        filename-pattern="*.*" remote-directory="${remote.pdb.directory}" 
        local-directory="${local.pdb.directory}">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter
        id="galaxyInbound"
          session-factory="sftpSessionFactory" 
        auto-create-local-directory="true" delete-remote-files="true"
        filename-pattern="*.*" remote-directory="${remote.galaxy.directory}"
        local-directory="${local.galaxy.directory}"  >
        <int:poller fixed-rate="5000"/>
    </int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Above code works perfectly fine and files are copied to local directories as expected.

Problem appears when I need to transfer these files to remote directory with the same directory structure as that of source directory. I could not achieve it using sftp-outbound gateway with command = "mput" and command-options= "-R". So, I tried to write two outbound adapters as below. But only one directory is written to remote.
Any idea what is going wrong here ?

```
    <int:service-activator input-channel="pdbInbound" output-channel="pdbOutbound" expression="payload"/> 
        <int:service-activator input-channel="galaxyInbound" output-channel="galaxyOutbound" expression="payload"/> 

        <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftPdbOutboundAdapter" auto-create-directory="true"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
             auto-startup="true"
            channel="pdbOutbound"
            charset="UTF-8"
            remote-file-separator="/"
            remote-directory="${remote.out.pdb.directory}"
             mode="REPLACE">
        </int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter>

        <int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpGalaxyOutboundAdapter" auto-create-directory="true"
             auto-startup="true"
            session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
            channel="galaxyOutbound"
            charset="UTF-8"
            remote-file-separator="/"
            remote-directory="${remote.out.galaxy.directory}"
             mode="REPLACE">
        </int-sftp:outbound-channel-adapter> 

 <int:poller default="true" fixed-delay="50"/>
```

Note: I am using same sftp server (but different directories)  for inbound and outbound files for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain your issues in more details - "did not work" is woefully inadequate and you won't get much help here with such a question. You need to show what you tried and what you observed.

There are test cases for both [recursive mget](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound/SftpServerOutboundTests.java#L210) and [recursive mput](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/sftp/outbound/SftpServerOutboundTests.java#L346).

The directory structure for the tests is shown in a comment at the top of that file.

I suggest you compare those with what you tried and come back here if you have a specific question/observation. Best thing to do to solve these issues is to turn on DEBUG logging; including for jsch.